# Date of release AnyTime

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am trying to create query which will return all items which is cancel, but which is release anytime.

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2) as tarifa, count(*) as komada
from pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where (datum_dop >= '1-jan-12')  AND (datum_dop <= '31-dec-12') 
and   p.orgjed = u.sorgz  (+)
and   p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0
group by substr(tarifa,1,2);
```

I have column `release(izdavanje)` in my table, and when I try something like this in my database browser

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2) as tarifa, count(*) as komada
from pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where (datum_dop >= '1-jan-12')  AND (datum_dop <= '31-dec-12')
and   (izdavanje >= '1-jun-12') AND (izdavanje  <= '28-jun-12')
and   p.orgjed = u.sorgz  (+)
and   p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0
group by substr(tarifa,1,2);
```

But I get error ORA-00911 Invalid character. Can someone tell me where I made mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should seriously switch to using modern join syntax.  And also, you should use valid Oracle date literals:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(tarifa, 1, 2) AS tarifa,
    COUNT(*) AS komada
FROM pol p
LEFT JOIN uvod u
    ON p.orgjed = u.sorgz
INNER JOIN doppov d
    p.polica = d.polica
WHERE
    datum_dop BETWEEN DATE '2012-01-01' AND DATE '2012-12-31' AND
    izdavanje BETWEEN DATE '2012-06-01' AND DATE '2012-06-28' AND
    d.pov_dopl = 'P' AND
    d.status = 'F' AND
    cisti_ao(p.polica) != 0
GROUP BY
    SUBSTR(tarifa, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you :) I use old version of Oracle, I belive it's 6i that why I wrote query in old style :)

Comment: Oh dear...that's before 1992 `:-(` ... maybe you need this syntax.  In this case, you should show us sample input and output data, and why your current query has a problem.

Comment: I resolve problem. The problem is that my version on IDE (Database Browser) in the end doesn't accept ; 
So  GROUP BY (tarifa,1,2) without ; 
But this work for me :) 
Thank you :)

Comment: Is this query same or not ? 
and   izdavanje  BETWEEN :prebacivanje.od AND :prebacivanje.do 
(izdavanje  >= :prebacivanje.od)  AND (izdavanje  <= :prebacivanje.do)

Comment: Oracle 6 was released in 1988, I doubt that's the version your are using. ANSI join syntax was introduced with Oracle 9i, i.e. 2001

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That's earlier than Super Nintendo.  Doubtful that anyone would still be using it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I belive something like this. I am not sure. My form builder is version 6. But it's very old

Comment: Is this query same or not ? and izdavanje BETWEEN :prebacivanje.od AND :prebacivanje.do (izdavanje >= :prebacivanje.od) AND (izdavanje <= :prebacivanje.do)

Comment: to be able to use the queries with modern SQL syntax, try moving them from Forms(I suppose they're embedded within the Forms) to stored DB procedures/functions/packages.

Comment: Oracle Forms 6i was released at the same time as Oracle Database 8i. I suspect Robby is referring to his Forms version, not his database version.